# Faster method for replacing multiple words in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a mini-translator for Japanese words for a given file.

The script have an expandable dictionary file that includes 13k+ lines in this format:-

```
JapaneseWord<:to:>EnglishWord
```

So I have to pick a line from the dictionary, then do a .strip('') to make a list in this format:-

[JapaneseWord,EnglishWord]

then I have to pick a line from the given file, and find the first item in this list in the line and replace it with its English equivalent, and I have to make sure to repeat this process in the same line for the number of times that Japanese word appears with the .count() function.

the problem is that this takes a long time because like this, I have to read the file again and again for 14k+ times, and this will expand as I expand the dictionary size.

I tried looking for a way to add the whole dictionary in the memory, and then compare them all in the given file at the same time, so like this, I will have to read the file one time, but I couldn't do it.

Here's the function I am using right now, it takes a var that includes the file's lines as a list with the file.readlines() function:-

```py
def replacer(text):

    #Current Dictionary.
    cdic = open(argv[4], 'r', encoding='utf-8')

    #Part To Replace.
    for ptorep in cdic:
        ptorep = ptorep.strip('\n')
        ptorep = ptorep.split('<:to:>')
        for line in text:
                for clone in range(0, line.count(ptorep[0])):
                    line = line.replace(ptorep[0], ptorep[1])
    text = ''.join(text)
    return text
```

This takes around 1 min for a single small file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Dictionary Method:

```py
import re

with open(argv[4], 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    translations = [line.strip('\n').split('<:to:>') for line in file.readlines()]
translations = {t[0]:t[1] for t in translations}    # Convert to dictionary where the key is the english word and the value is the translation

output = []
for word in re.split('\W+'):    # Split into words (may require tweaking)
    output.append(translations.get(word, word))    # Search for the key `word`, in case it does not exist, use `word`
output = ''.join(output)
```

---

### Original Method:

Maybe keep the full dictionary in memory as a `list`:

```py
cdic = open(argv[4], 'r', encoding='utf-8')

translations = []
for line in cdic.readlines():
    translations.append(line.strip('\n').split('<:to:>'))


# Note: I would use a list comprehension for this
with open(argv[4], 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    translations = [line.strip('\n').split('<:to:>') for line in file.readlines()]
```

And make the replacements off of that:

```py
def replacer(text, translations):
    for entry in translations:
        text = text.replace(entry[0], entry[1])
    return text
```

Comment: it really didn't make a noticeable difference, it took nearly the same time

Comment: Could you given an example of the dictionary and some input text? Also are you rebuilding the dictionary on every input? If not, the issue is probably in the replace loop which can be solved with a different replacement system (like with a `dict`).

Comment: This is a rewritten dictionary in a dedicated file, but using .replace() with an var equal to file.read() is alot faster but I need to check every line by line with the list method for many reasons so i cannot use .read() and iam stuck to only use .readlines()

Comment: can you tell me more about that different replacement system you mentioned?

Comment: Yeah, if you have a list of all the words, then you can replace each word by accessing a dictionary (which should be constant time). I'll update the answer with an implementation of this method.